# KeyListener doesn't trigger

Tags: java, keylistener

This is a alpha code for a calculator that I'm making, and I want it to be that when I press "1" the calculator inputs 1 in my array but it isn't even triggering the keyPressed and that.

```
package ws1;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ws41 extends Applet implements ActionListener, KeyListener{
    Button equals,zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,divide,times,plus,minus,u2s,s2u,period;
    Label show;
    double total;
    double dot;
    double left=0;
    double right=0;
    String tots = "";
    String sign = "";
    ArrayList<Integer> Calc = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public void init(){
        setSize(30,200);
        show = new Label("");
        period = new Button(" . ");
        u2s = new Button(" Usd to Sek");
        s2u = new Button("Sek to Usd");
        zero = new Button(" 0 ");
        one = new Button(" 1 ");
        two = new Button(" 2 ");
        three = new Button(" 3 ");
        four = new Button(" 4 ");
        five = new Button(" 5 ");
        six = new Button(" 6 ");
        seven = new Button(" 7 ");
        eight = new Button(" 8 ");
        nine = new Button(" 9 ");
        plus = new Button(" + ");
        minus = new Button(" - ");
        times = new Button(" * ");
        divide = new Button(" / ");
        equals = new Button(" = ");
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        zero.addActionListener (this);
        one.addActionListener (this);
        two.addActionListener (this);
        three.addActionListener (this);
        four.addActionListener (this);
        five.addActionListener (this);
        six.addActionListener (this);
        seven.addActionListener (this);
        eight.addActionListener (this);
        nine.addActionListener (this);
        plus.addActionListener (this);
        times.addActionListener (this);
        minus.addActionListener (this);
        times.addActionListener (this);
        divide.addActionListener (this);
        equals.addActionListener (this);
        u2s.addActionListener (this);
        s2u.addActionListener (this);
        period.addActionListener(this);
        //add(show);
        add(one);
        add(two);
        add(three);
        add(four);
        add(five);
        add(six);
        add(seven);
        add(eight);
        add(nine);
        add(zero);
        add(period);
        add(plus);
        add(minus);
        add(times);
        add(divide);
        add(equals);
        add(u2s);
        add(s2u);
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
        Calc.add(ke.getKeyCode());
    }


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke){
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
    }
```

Comment: Consider posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You have posted a lot of code for a very small problem.

Comment: "when i press "1" the calculator inputs 1" Press 1 on the keyboard or 1 on the calculator?

Comment: One on the keyboard

Sorry, shortened it

Comment: You should not be using KeyListener on buttons, instead you should be using ActionListener. In fact, you could greatly simplify this by using the [Action API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), as the Action would be shared between the button and the key binding

Comment: If you know your code is "messy and unorganized" you should try to clean it up before posting here. You will always get better answers if you make it easy to read your code and question.

Answer (score 0):

`KeyListener` is focus contextual. That is, it will only respond to key event s when the component it is registered to has focus (and is focusable)

AWT is 15+ years out of date  and was replaced with Swing. Consider using Swing based components instead

You should not be using `KeyListener` on buttons, instead you should be using `ActionListener`.

See [How to use buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to write ActionListeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details

In fact, you could greatly simplify this by using the [`Action` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), as the `Action` would be shared between the button and the key binding

Comment: But he isn't using buttons is he? `"One on the keyboard Sorry, shortened it –  Chris"`

Comment: @zach They are, they are expecting that when they press the corresponding key on the keyboard, the associated button will be triggered, they are adding KeyListensers to buttons

Comment: @Takendarkk They could be a team...?

Comment: Oh ok I see what you mean